# Parsley form will not validate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, parsley.js

I've tried to duplicate the  sample bootstrap/parsley form in jsfiddle
with bootstrap 3 parsley 2.2.0-rc4
http://jsfiddle.net/bwolfsohn/9wfjo94w/14/

the form pops up the message: Yay, everything seems to be ok..
then errors out with:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x2971b90>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x2997bd0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x2971b90>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x29974d0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

The original sample is at:
http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Comment: There's a "Try it on CodePen" button that makes it easy to play with it... Doesn't look apparent enough if you didn't see it, right?

Comment: i saw the "try it on codepen".  the link doesn't go anywhere.. it's just "#"

Comment: i also updated the fiddle and verified all the external resources are good..

http://jsfiddle.net/bwolfsohn/m13gL20d/

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune  i manually uploaded and ran it on codepen with no problems... all is good..

Comment: Indeed, 'codepen' button didn't work in Firefox. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. This looks like a jsfiddle problem...
I manually loaded it and ran it on codepen with no problem...

http://codepen.io/bwolfsohn/pen/dGbePr

```
You've just POSTed to a Pen.
Values Posted
fullname    brian wolfsohn
email   brian@cus.com
gender  M
message     
Values as JSON
{"fullname":"brian wolfsohn","email":"abc@def.com","gender":"M","message":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what that error is, but I've updated the example, hopefully it will make things clearer and better.